# how to make r script run periodically without human invention

Tags: r, operating-system

Right now I wrote some script that could analyze the daily dumped file from Hadoop. What I want is to let my R script runs daily at 4AM after new data becomes available. Is there any script from R side or OS side could make this happen automatically?

What I can think of is to leave have another R script idling and keep checking system time to decide to call my script to run, but is this too much? I prefer to have R closed unless necessarily.

OK, I see the answer. Does anyone have experience commenting on the stability between R and Python, in terms of running large scale data processing task.

Comment: What operating system are you running on? You could get a cron job setup if you're on Linux or OS X or use the Windows scheduled tasks.

Comment: you could do a chron job to run the script

Answer (score 3):

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

-or better yet-

http://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/schedule-rscript-with-cron/

Those websites should be all you need to get it going.  Assuming you are using linux.

Comment: Here's [another good link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: hahaha, @RichardScriven, I have never seen that before but I will take that into account from now on.  I still say let the man fish, especially for something like this.

Comment: OK, I see the point. But does R has some internal recovery system that in case R closed unexpectedly, it can try again without problem next time, say one hour later? My company server administer keep telling me R is unstable and suggest me using Python instead

Comment: I don't know about all that.  I've used R only a handful of times.  Maybe you could set up a script that periodically runs the R script until it gets a desired return value from R.  Then queue up the other script in the cron job, that might be a roundabout way of doing it though.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code

```html
Sys.time()
for(period in 1:365){
  
  {
    your code here
  }

  newdate=as.POSIXct("2014-11-14 04:00:00 GMT")+24*60*60*period
  Sys.sleep(  newdate  - Sys.time() )  
}
```